# Convert nested dictionary, list, and dictionary into a pandas data frame in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So, I am trying to work with a rest API, and it is giving me the following data:

```
{'sports': [{'id': '20',
   'uid': 's:20',
   'name': 'Football',
   'slug': 'football',
   'leagues': [{'id': '28',
     'uid': 's:20~l:28',
     'name': 'National Football League',
     'abbreviation': 'NFL',
     'shortName': 'NFL',
     'slug': 'nfl',
     'teams': [{'team': {'id': '22',
        'uid': 's:20~l:28~t:22',
        'slug': 'arizona-cardinals',
        'location': 'Arizona',
        'name': 'Cardinals',
        'nickname': 'Cardinals',
        'abbreviation': 'ARI',
        'displayName': 'Arizona Cardinals',
        'shortDisplayName': 'Cardinals',
        'color': 'A40227',
        'alternateColor': '000000',
        'isActive': True,
        'isAllStar': False,
        'logos': [{'href': 'https://a.espncdn.com/i/teamlogos/nfl/500/ari.png',
          'width': 500,
          'height': 500,
          'alt': '',
          'rel': ['full', 'default'],
          'lastUpdated': '2018-06-05T12:11Z'},
         {'href': 'https://a.espncdn.com/i/teamlogos/nfl/500-dark/ari.png',
          'width': 500,
          'height': 500,
          'alt': '',
          'rel': ['full', 'dark'],
          'lastUpdated': '2018-06-05T12:11Z'},
         {'href': 'https://a.espncdn.com/i/teamlogos/nfl/500/scoreboard/ari.png',
          'width': 500,
          'height': 500,
          'alt': '',
          'rel': ['full', 'scoreboard'],
          'lastUpdated': '2018-06-05T12:11Z'},
...
```

I'm just interested in the `teams` data. However, I try to slice the pie, I'm having trouble extracting the desired information into the dataframe properly.

Here is my code:

```
url = 'http://site.api.espn.com/apis/site/v2/sports/football/nfl/teams'

r = requests.get(url)
teams_json = r.json()

nfl = []

for teams in teams_json.items():
    
    for x in teams:
        
        for row in x:
            print(row['teams'])
```

I keep getting errors.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest looking into how to navigate lists and dictionaries in python (that's all that json files are). It's just a matter of knowing the path, or how to iterate through those.

To get into a dataframe, `pandas` has a nice `.json_normalize()` method. I'm not sure what data you want exactly, as the root `teams` key data is also nested. So depending what you are after, you may need to do a little extra work to extract what you want. But this is the general dataframe for `teams`.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://site.api.espn.com/apis/site/v2/sports/football/nfl/teams'

jsonData = requests.get(url).json()
teams_json = jsonData['sports'][0]['leagues'][0]['teams']

df = pd.json_normalize(teams_json)
```

**Output:**

```
print(df.head().to_string())
  team.id        team.uid           team.slug team.location  team.name team.nickname team.abbreviation    team.displayName team.shortDisplayName team.color team.alternateColor  team.isActive  team.isAllStar                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               team.logos                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          team.record.items                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            team.links
0      22  s:20~l:28~t:22   arizona-cardinals       Arizona  Cardinals     Cardinals               ARI   Arizona Cardinals             Cardinals     A40227              000000           True           False  [{'href': 'https://a.espncdn.com/i/teamlogos/nfl/500/ari.png', 'width': 500, 'height': 500, 'alt': '', 'rel': ['full', 'default'], 'lastUpdated': '2018-06-05T12:11Z'}, {'href': 'https://a.espncdn.com/i/teamlogos/nfl/500-dark/ari.png', 'width': 500, 'height': 500, 'alt': '', 'rel': ['full', 'dark'], 'lastUpdated': '2018-06-05T12:11Z'}, {'href': 'https://a.espncdn.com/i/teamlogos/nfl/500/scoreboard/ari.png', 'width': 500, 'height': 500, 'alt': '', 'rel': ['full', 'scoreboard'], 'lastUpdated': '2018-06-05T12:11Z'}, {'href': 'https://a.espncdn.com/i/teamlogos/nfl/500-dark/scoreboard/ari.png', 'width': 500, 'height': 500, 'alt': '', 'rel': ['full', 'scoreboard', 'dark'], 'lastUpdated': '2018-06-05T12:11Z'}]       [{'summary': '11-6', 'stats': [{'name': 'playoffSeed', 'value': 5.0}, {'name': 'wins', 'value': 11.0}, {'name': 'losses', 'value': 6.0}, {'name': 'winPercent', 'value': 0.6470588445663452}, {'name': 'gamesBehind', 'value': 0.0}, {'name': 'ties', 'value': 0.0}, {'name': 'OTWins', 'value': 0.0}, {'name': 'OTLosses', 'value': 0.0}, {'name': 'gamesPlayed', 'value': 17.0}, {'name': 'pointsFor', 'value': 449.0}, {'name': 'pointsAgainst', 'value': 366.0}, {'name': 'avgPointsFor', 'value': 26.41176414489746}, {'name': 'avgPointsAgainst', 'value': 21.52941131591797}, {'name': 'points', 'value': 2.5}, {'name': 'differential', 'value': 83.0}, {'name': 'streak', 'value': -1.0}, {'name': 'clincher', 'value': 0.0}, {'name': 'divisionWinPercent', 'value': 0.6666666865348816}, {'name': 'leagueWinPercent', 'value': 0.5833333134651184}, {'name': 'divisionRecord', 'value': 0.0}, {'name': 'divisionWins', 'value': 4.0}, {'name': 'divisionTies', 'value': 0.0}, {'name': 'divisionLosses', 'value': 2.0}]}]      [{'language': 'en-US', 'rel': ['clubhouse', 'desktop', 'team'], 'href': 'https://www.espn.com/nfl/team/_/name/ari/arizona-cardinals', 'text': 'Clubhouse', 'shortText': 'Clubhouse', 'isExternal': False, 'isPremium': False}, {'language': 'en-US', 'rel': ['roster', 'desktop', 'team'], 'href': 'http://www.espn.com/nfl/team/roster/_/name/ari/arizona-cardinals', 'text': 'Roster', 'shortText': 'Roster', 'isExternal': False, 'isPremium': False}, {'language': 'en-US', 'rel': ['stats', 'desktop', 'team'], 'href': 'http://www.espn.com/nfl/team/stats/_/name/ari/arizona-cardinals', 'text': 'Statistics', 'shortText': 'Statistics', 'isExternal': False, 'isPremium': False}, {'language': 'en-US', 'rel': ['schedule', 'desktop', 'team'], 'href': 'https://www.espn.com/nfl/team/schedule/_/name/ari', 'text': 'Schedule', 'shortText': 'Schedule', 'isExternal': False, 'isPremium': False}, {'language': 'en-US', 'rel': ['photos', 'desktop', 'team'], 'href': 'https://www.espn.com/nfl/team/photos/_/name/ari', 'text': 'photos', 'shortText': 'photos', 'isExternal': False, 'isPremium': False}, {'language': 'en-US', 'rel': ['scores', 'sportscenter', 'app', 'team'], 'href': 'sportscenter://x-callback-url/showClubhouse?uid=s:20~l:28~t:22&section=scores', 'text': 'Scores', 'shortText': 'Scores', 'isExternal': False, 'isPremium': False}, {'language': 'en-US', 'rel': ['draftpicks', 'desktop', 'team'], 'href': 'http://www.espn.com/nfl/draft/teams/_/name/ari/arizona-cardinals', 'text': 'Draft Picks', 'shortText': 'Draft Picks', 'isExternal': False, 'isPremium': True}, {'language': 'en-US', 'rel': ['transactions', 'desktop', 'team'], 'href': 'https://www.espn.com/nfl/team/transactions/_/name/ari', 'text': 'Transactions', 'shortText': 'Transactions', 'isExternal': False, 'isPremium': False}, {'language': 'en-US', 'rel': ['injuries', 'desktop', 'team'], 'href': 'https://www.espn.com/nfl/team/injuries/_/name/ari', 'text': 'Injuries', 'shortText': 'Injuries', 'isExternal': False, 'isPremium': False}, {'language': 'en-US', 'rel': ['depthchart', 'desktop', 'team'], 'href': 'https://www.espn.com/nfl/team/depth/_/name/ari', 'text': 'Depth Chart', 'shortText': 'Depth Chart', 'isExternal': False, 'isPremium': False}, {'language': 'en', 'rel': ['tickets', 'desktop', 'team'], 'href': 'https://www.vividseats.com/nfl-football/arizona-cardinals-tickets.html?wsUser=717', 'text': 'Tickets', 'isExternal': True, 'isPremium': False}]
1       1   s:20~l:28~t:1     atlanta-falcons       Atlanta    Falcons       Falcons               ATL     Atlanta Falcons               Falcons     000000              000000           True           False  [{'href': 'https://a.espncdn.com/i/teamlogos/nfl/500/atl.png', 'width': 500, 'height': 500, 'alt': '', 'rel': ['full', 'default'], 'lastUpdated': '2018-06-05T12:11Z'}, {'href': 'https://a.espncdn.com/i/teamlogos/nfl/500-dark/atl.png', 'width': 500, 'height': 500, 'alt': '', 'rel': ['full', 'dark'], 'lastUpdated': '2018-06-05T12:11Z'}, {'href': 'https://a.espncdn.com/i/teamlogos/nfl/500/scoreboard/atl.png', 'width': 500, 'height': 500, 'alt': '', 'rel': ['full', 'scoreboard'], 'lastUpdated': '2018-06-05T12:11Z'}, {'href': 'https://a.espncdn.com/i/teamlogos/nfl/500-dark/scoreboard/atl.png', 'width': 500, 'height': 500, 'alt': '', 'rel': ['full', 'scoreboard', 'dark'], 'lastUpdated': '2018-06-05T12:11Z'}]                [{'summary': '7-10', 'stats': [{'name': 'playoffSeed', 'value': 12.0}, {'name': 'wins', 'value': 7.0}, {'name': 'losses', 'value': 10.0}, {'name': 'winPercent', 'value': 0.4117647111415863}, {'name': 'gamesBehind', 'value': 0.0}, {'name': 'ties', 'value': 0.0}, {'name': 'OTWins', 'value': 0.0}, {'name': 'OTLosses', 'value': 0.0}, {'name': 'gamesPlayed', 'value': 17.0}, {'name': 'pointsFor', 'value': 313.0}, {'name': 'pointsAgainst', 'value': 459.0}, {'name': 'avgPointsFor', 'value': 18.41176414489746}, {'name': 'avgPointsAgainst', 'value': 27.0}, {'name': 'points', 'value': -1.5}, {'name': 'differential', 'value': -146.0}, {'name': 'streak', 'value': -2.0}, {'name': 'clincher', 'value': 0.0}, {'name': 'divisionWinPercent', 'value': 0.3333333432674408}, {'name': 'leagueWinPercent', 'value': 0.3333333432674408}, {'name': 'divisionRecord', 'value': 0.0}, {'name': 'divisionWins', 'value': 2.0}, {'name': 'divisionTies', 'value': 0.0}, {'name': 'divisionLosses', 'value': 4.0}]}]                 [{'language': 'en-US', 'rel': ['clubhouse', 'desktop', 'team'], 'href': 'https://www.espn.com/nfl/team/_/name/atl/atlanta-falcons', 'text': 'Clubhouse', 'shortText': 'Clubhouse', 'isExternal': False, 'isPremium': False}, {'language': 'en-US', 'rel': ['roster', 'desktop', 'team'], 'href': 'http://www.espn.com/nfl/team/roster/_/name/atl/atlanta-falcons', 'text': 'Roster', 'shortText': 'Roster', 'isExternal': False, 'isPremium': False}, {'language': 'en-US', 'rel': ['stats', 'desktop', 'team'], 'href': 'http://www.espn.com/nfl/team/stats/_/name/atl/atlanta-falcons', 'text': 'Statistics', 'shortText': 'Statistics', 'isExternal': False, 'isPremium': False}, {'language': 'en-US', 'rel': ['schedule', 'desktop', 'team'], 'href': 'https://www.espn.com/nfl/team/schedule/_/name/atl', 'text': 'Schedule', 'shortText': 'Schedule', 'isExternal': False, 'isPremium': False}, {'language': 'en-US', 'rel': ['photos', 'desktop', 'team'], 'href': 'https://www.espn.com/nfl/team/photos/_/name/atl', 'text': 'photos', 'shortText': 'photos', 'isExternal': False, 'isPremium': False}, {'language': 'en-US', 'rel': ['scores', 'sportscenter', 'app', 'team'], 'href': 'sportscenter://x-callback-url/showClubhouse?uid=s:20~l:28~t:1&section=scores', 'text': 'Scores', 'shortText': 'Scores', 'isExternal': False, 'isPremium': False}, {'language': 'en-US', 'rel': ['draftpicks', 'desktop', 'team'], 'href': 'http://www.espn.com/nfl/draft/teams/_/name/atl/atlanta-falcons', 'text': 'Draft Picks', 'shortText': 'Draft Picks', 'isExternal': False, 'isPremium': True}, {'language': 'en-US', 'rel': ['transactions', 'desktop', 'team'], 'href': 'https://www.espn.com/nfl/team/transactions/_/name/atl', 'text': 'Transactions', 'shortText': 'Transactions', 'isExternal': False, 'isPremium': False}, {'language': 'en-US', 'rel': ['injuries', 'desktop', 'team'], 'href': 'https://www.espn.com/nfl/team/injuries/_/name/atl', 'text': 'Injuries', 'shortText': 'Injuries', 'isExternal': False, 'isPremium': False}, {'language': 'en-US', 'rel': ['depthchart', 'desktop', 'team'], 'href': 'https://www.espn.com/nfl/team/depth/_/name/atl', 'text': 'Depth Chart', 'shortText': 'Depth Chart', 'isExternal': False, 'isPremium': False}, {'language': 'en', 'rel': ['tickets', 'desktop', 'team'], 'href': 'https://www.vividseats.com/nfl-football/atlanta-falcons-tickets.html?wsUser=717', 'text': 'Tickets', 'isExternal': True, 'isPremium': False}]
2       2   s:20~l:28~t:2       buffalo-bills       Buffalo      Bills         Bills               BUF       Buffalo Bills                 Bills     04407F              c60c30           True           False  [{'href': 'https://a.espncdn.com/i/teamlogos/nfl/500/buf.png', 'width': 500, 'height': 500, 'alt': '', 'rel': ['full', 'default'], 'lastUpdated': '2018-06-05T12:11Z'}, {'href': 'https://a.espncdn.com/i/teamlogos/nfl/500-dark/buf.png', 'width': 500, 'height': 500, 'alt': '', 'rel': ['full', 'dark'], 'lastUpdated': '2018-06-05T12:11Z'}, {'href': 'https://a.espncdn.com/i/teamlogos/nfl/500/scoreboard/buf.png', 'width': 500, 'height': 500, 'alt': '', 'rel': ['full', 'scoreboard'], 'lastUpdated': '2018-06-05T12:11Z'}, {'href': 'https://a.espncdn.com/i/teamlogos/nfl/500-dark/scoreboard/buf.png', 'width': 500, 'height': 500, 'alt': '', 'rel': ['full', 'scoreboard', 'dark'], 'lastUpdated': '2018-06-05T12:11Z'}]                    [{'summary': '11-6', 'stats': [{'name': 'playoffSeed', 'value': 3.0}, {'name': 'wins', 'value': 11.0}, {'name': 'losses', 'value': 6.0}, {'name': 'winPercent', 'value': 0.6470588445663452}, {'name': 'gamesBehind', 'value': 0.0}, {'name': 'ties', 'value': 0.0}, {'name': 'OTWins', 'value': 0.0}, {'name': 'OTLosses', 'value': 1.0}, {'name': 'gamesPlayed', 'value': 17.0}, {'name': 'pointsFor', 'value': 483.0}, {'name': 'pointsAgainst', 'value': 289.0}, {'name': 'avgPointsFor', 'value': 28.41176414489746}, {'name': 'avgPointsAgainst', 'value': 17.0}, {'name': 'points', 'value': 2.5}, {'name': 'differential', 'value': 194.0}, {'name': 'streak', 'value': 4.0}, {'name': 'clincher', 'value': 0.0}, {'name': 'divisionWinPercent', 'value': 0.8333333134651184}, {'name': 'leagueWinPercent', 'value': 0.5833333134651184}, {'name': 'divisionRecord', 'value': 0.0}, {'name': 'divisionWins', 'value': 5.0}, {'name': 'divisionTies', 'value': 0.0}, {'name': 'divisionLosses', 'value': 1.0}]}]                           [{'language': 'en-US', 'rel': ['clubhouse', 'desktop', 'team'], 'href': 'https://www.espn.com/nfl/team/_/name/buf/buffalo-bills', 'text': 'Clubhouse', 'shortText': 'Clubhouse', 'isExternal': False, 'isPremium': False}, {'language': 'en-US', 'rel': ['roster', 'desktop', 'team'], 'href': 'http://www.espn.com/nfl/team/roster/_/name/buf/buffalo-bills', 'text': 'Roster', 'shortText': 'Roster', 'isExternal': False, 'isPremium': False}, {'language': 'en-US', 'rel': ['stats', 'desktop', 'team'], 'href': 'http://www.espn.com/nfl/team/stats/_/name/buf/buffalo-bills', 'text': 'Statistics', 'shortText': 'Statistics', 'isExternal': False, 'isPremium': False}, {'language': 'en-US', 'rel': ['schedule', 'desktop', 'team'], 'href': 'https://www.espn.com/nfl/team/schedule/_/name/buf', 'text': 'Schedule', 'shortText': 'Schedule', 'isExternal': False, 'isPremium': False}, {'language': 'en-US', 'rel': ['photos', 'desktop', 'team'], 'href': 'https://www.espn.com/nfl/team/photos/_/name/buf', 'text': 'photos', 'shortText': 'photos', 'isExternal': False, 'isPremium': False}, {'language': 'en-US', 'rel': ['scores', 'sportscenter', 'app', 'team'], 'href': 'sportscenter://x-callback-url/showClubhouse?uid=s:20~l:28~t:2&section=scores', 'text': 'Scores', 'shortText': 'Scores', 'isExternal': False, 'isPremium': False}, {'language': 'en-US', 'rel': ['draftpicks', 'desktop', 'team'], 'href': 'http://www.espn.com/nfl/draft/teams/_/name/buf/buffalo-bills', 'text': 'Draft Picks', 'shortText': 'Draft Picks', 'isExternal': False, 'isPremium': True}, {'language': 'en-US', 'rel': ['transactions', 'desktop', 'team'], 'href': 'https://www.espn.com/nfl/team/transactions/_/name/buf', 'text': 'Transactions', 'shortText': 'Transactions', 'isExternal': False, 'isPremium': False}, {'language': 'en-US', 'rel': ['injuries', 'desktop', 'team'], 'href': 'https://www.espn.com/nfl/team/injuries/_/name/buf', 'text': 'Injuries', 'shortText': 'Injuries', 'isExternal': False, 'isPremium': False}, {'language': 'en-US', 'rel': ['depthchart', 'desktop', 'team'], 'href': 'https://www.espn.com/nfl/team/depth/_/name/buf', 'text': 'Depth Chart', 'shortText': 'Depth Chart', 'isExternal': False, 'isPremium': False}, {'language': 'en', 'rel': ['tickets', 'desktop', 'team'], 'href': 'https://www.vividseats.com/nfl-football/buffalo-bills-tickets.html?wsUser=717', 'text': 'Tickets', 'isExternal': True, 'isPremium': False}]
3       3   s:20~l:28~t:3       chicago-bears       Chicago      Bears         Bears               CHI       Chicago Bears                 Bears     152644              0b162a           True           False  [{'href': 'https://a.espncdn.com/i/teamlogos/nfl/500/chi.png', 'width': 500, 'height': 500, 'alt': '', 'rel': ['full', 'default'], 'lastUpdated': '2018-06-05T12:11Z'}, {'href': 'https://a.espncdn.com/i/teamlogos/nfl/500-dark/chi.png', 'width': 500, 'height': 500, 'alt': '', 'rel': ['full', 'dark'], 'lastUpdated': '2018-06-05T12:11Z'}, {'href': 'https://a.espncdn.com/i/teamlogos/nfl/500/scoreboard/chi.png', 'width': 500, 'height': 500, 'alt': '', 'rel': ['full', 'scoreboard'], 'lastUpdated': '2018-06-05T12:11Z'}, {'href': 'https://a.espncdn.com/i/teamlogos/nfl/500-dark/scoreboard/chi.png', 'width': 500, 'height': 500, 'alt': '', 'rel': ['full', 'scoreboard', 'dark'], 'lastUpdated': '2018-06-05T12:11Z'}]  [{'summary': '6-11', 'stats': [{'name': 'playoffSeed', 'value': 13.0}, {'name': 'wins', 'value': 6.0}, {'name': 'losses', 'value': 11.0}, {'name': 'winPercent', 'value': 0.3529411852359772}, {'name': 'gamesBehind', 'value': 0.0}, {'name': 'ties', 'value': 0.0}, {'name': 'OTWins', 'value': 0.0}, {'name': 'OTLosses', 'value': 0.0}, {'name': 'gamesPlayed', 'value': 17.0}, {'name': 'pointsFor', 'value': 311.0}, {'name': 'pointsAgainst', 'value': 407.0}, {'name': 'avgPointsFor', 'value': 18.294116973876953}, {'name': 'avgPointsAgainst', 'value': 23.941177368164062}, {'name': 'points', 'value': -2.5}, {'name': 'differential', 'value': -96.0}, {'name': 'streak', 'value': -1.0}, {'name': 'clincher', 'value': 0.0}, {'name': 'divisionWinPercent', 'value': 0.3333333432674408}, {'name': 'leagueWinPercent', 'value': 0.3333333432674408}, {'name': 'divisionRecord', 'value': 0.0}, {'name': 'divisionWins', 'value': 2.0}, {'name': 'divisionTies', 'value': 0.0}, {'name': 'divisionLosses', 'value': 4.0}]}]                           [{'language': 'en-US', 'rel': ['clubhouse', 'desktop', 'team'], 'href': 'https://www.espn.com/nfl/team/_/name/chi/chicago-bears', 'text': 'Clubhouse', 'shortText': 'Clubhouse', 'isExternal': False, 'isPremium': False}, {'language': 'en-US', 'rel': ['roster', 'desktop', 'team'], 'href': 'http://www.espn.com/nfl/team/roster/_/name/chi/chicago-bears', 'text': 'Roster', 'shortText': 'Roster', 'isExternal': False, 'isPremium': False}, {'language': 'en-US', 'rel': ['stats', 'desktop', 'team'], 'href': 'http://www.espn.com/nfl/team/stats/_/name/chi/chicago-bears', 'text': 'Statistics', 'shortText': 'Statistics', 'isExternal': False, 'isPremium': False}, {'language': 'en-US', 'rel': ['schedule', 'desktop', 'team'], 'href': 'https://www.espn.com/nfl/team/schedule/_/name/chi', 'text': 'Schedule', 'shortText': 'Schedule', 'isExternal': False, 'isPremium': False}, {'language': 'en-US', 'rel': ['photos', 'desktop', 'team'], 'href': 'https://www.espn.com/nfl/team/photos/_/name/chi', 'text': 'photos', 'shortText': 'photos', 'isExternal': False, 'isPremium': False}, {'language': 'en-US', 'rel': ['scores', 'sportscenter', 'app', 'team'], 'href': 'sportscenter://x-callback-url/showClubhouse?uid=s:20~l:28~t:3&section=scores', 'text': 'Scores', 'shortText': 'Scores', 'isExternal': False, 'isPremium': False}, {'language': 'en-US', 'rel': ['draftpicks', 'desktop', 'team'], 'href': 'http://www.espn.com/nfl/draft/teams/_/name/chi/chicago-bears', 'text': 'Draft Picks', 'shortText': 'Draft Picks', 'isExternal': False, 'isPremium': True}, {'language': 'en-US', 'rel': ['transactions', 'desktop', 'team'], 'href': 'https://www.espn.com/nfl/team/transactions/_/name/chi', 'text': 'Transactions', 'shortText': 'Transactions', 'isExternal': False, 'isPremium': False}, {'language': 'en-US', 'rel': ['injuries', 'desktop', 'team'], 'href': 'https://www.espn.com/nfl/team/injuries/_/name/chi', 'text': 'Injuries', 'shortText': 'Injuries', 'isExternal': False, 'isPremium': False}, {'language': 'en-US', 'rel': ['depthchart', 'desktop', 'team'], 'href': 'https://www.espn.com/nfl/team/depth/_/name/chi', 'text': 'Depth Chart', 'shortText': 'Depth Chart', 'isExternal': False, 'isPremium': False}, {'language': 'en', 'rel': ['tickets', 'desktop', 'team'], 'href': 'https://www.vividseats.com/nfl-football/chicago-bears-tickets.html?wsUser=717', 'text': 'Tickets', 'isExternal': True, 'isPremium': False}]
4       4   s:20~l:28~t:4  cincinnati-bengals    Cincinnati    Bengals       Bengals               CIN  Cincinnati Bengals               Bengals     FF2700              000000           True           False  [{'href': 'https://a.espncdn.com/i/teamlogos/nfl/500/cin.png', 'width': 500, 'height': 500, 'alt': '', 'rel': ['full', 'default'], 'lastUpdated': '2018-06-05T12:11Z'}, {'href': 'https://a.espncdn.com/i/teamlogos/nfl/500-dark/cin.png', 'width': 500, 'height': 500, 'alt': '', 'rel': ['full', 'dark'], 'lastUpdated': '2018-06-05T12:11Z'}, {'href': 'https://a.espncdn.com/i/teamlogos/nfl/500/scoreboard/cin.png', 'width': 500, 'height': 500, 'alt': '', 'rel': ['full', 'scoreboard'], 'lastUpdated': '2018-06-05T12:11Z'}, {'href': 'https://a.espncdn.com/i/teamlogos/nfl/500-dark/scoreboard/cin.png', 'width': 500, 'height': 500, 'alt': '', 'rel': ['full', 'scoreboard', 'dark'], 'lastUpdated': '2018-06-05T12:11Z'}]     [{'summary': '10-7', 'stats': [{'name': 'playoffSeed', 'value': 4.0}, {'name': 'wins', 'value': 10.0}, {'name': 'losses', 'value': 7.0}, {'name': 'winPercent', 'value': 0.5882353186607361}, {'name': 'gamesBehind', 'value': 0.0}, {'name': 'ties', 'value': 0.0}, {'name': 'OTWins', 'value': 1.0}, {'name': 'OTLosses', 'value': 2.0}, {'name': 'gamesPlayed', 'value': 17.0}, {'name': 'pointsFor', 'value': 460.0}, {'name': 'pointsAgainst', 'value': 376.0}, {'name': 'avgPointsFor', 'value': 27.058822631835938}, {'name': 'avgPointsAgainst', 'value': 22.117647171020508}, {'name': 'points', 'value': 1.5}, {'name': 'differential', 'value': 84.0}, {'name': 'streak', 'value': -1.0}, {'name': 'clincher', 'value': 0.0}, {'name': 'divisionWinPercent', 'value': 0.6666666865348816}, {'name': 'leagueWinPercent', 'value': 0.6666666865348816}, {'name': 'divisionRecord', 'value': 0.0}, {'name': 'divisionWins', 'value': 4.0}, {'name': 'divisionTies', 'value': 0.0}, {'name': 'divisionLosses', 'value': 2.0}]}]  [{'language': 'en-US', 'rel': ['clubhouse', 'desktop', 'team'], 'href': 'https://www.espn.com/nfl/team/_/name/cin/cincinnati-bengals', 'text': 'Clubhouse', 'shortText': 'Clubhouse', 'isExternal': False, 'isPremium': False}, {'language': 'en-US', 'rel': ['roster', 'desktop', 'team'], 'href': 'http://www.espn.com/nfl/team/roster/_/name/cin/cincinnati-bengals', 'text': 'Roster', 'shortText': 'Roster', 'isExternal': False, 'isPremium': False}, {'language': 'en-US', 'rel': ['stats', 'desktop', 'team'], 'href': 'http://www.espn.com/nfl/team/stats/_/name/cin/cincinnati-bengals', 'text': 'Statistics', 'shortText': 'Statistics', 'isExternal': False, 'isPremium': False}, {'language': 'en-US', 'rel': ['schedule', 'desktop', 'team'], 'href': 'https://www.espn.com/nfl/team/schedule/_/name/cin', 'text': 'Schedule', 'shortText': 'Schedule', 'isExternal': False, 'isPremium': False}, {'language': 'en-US', 'rel': ['photos', 'desktop', 'team'], 'href': 'https://www.espn.com/nfl/team/photos/_/name/cin', 'text': 'photos', 'shortText': 'photos', 'isExternal': False, 'isPremium': False}, {'language': 'en-US', 'rel': ['scores', 'sportscenter', 'app', 'team'], 'href': 'sportscenter://x-callback-url/showClubhouse?uid=s:20~l:28~t:4&section=scores', 'text': 'Scores', 'shortText': 'Scores', 'isExternal': False, 'isPremium': False}, {'language': 'en-US', 'rel': ['draftpicks', 'desktop', 'team'], 'href': 'http://www.espn.com/nfl/draft/teams/_/name/cin/cincinnati-bengals', 'text': 'Draft Picks', 'shortText': 'Draft Picks', 'isExternal': False, 'isPremium': True}, {'language': 'en-US', 'rel': ['transactions', 'desktop', 'team'], 'href': 'https://www.espn.com/nfl/team/transactions/_/name/cin', 'text': 'Transactions', 'shortText': 'Transactions', 'isExternal': False, 'isPremium': False}, {'language': 'en-US', 'rel': ['injuries', 'desktop', 'team'], 'href': 'https://www.espn.com/nfl/team/injuries/_/name/cin', 'text': 'Injuries', 'shortText': 'Injuries', 'isExternal': False, 'isPremium': False}, {'language': 'en-US', 'rel': ['depthchart', 'desktop', 'team'], 'href': 'https://www.espn.com/nfl/team/depth/_/name/cin', 'text': 'Depth Chart', 'shortText': 'Depth Chart', 'isExternal': False, 'isPremium': False}, {'language': 'en', 'rel': ['tickets', 'desktop', 'team'], 'href': 'https://www.vividseats.com/nfl-football/cincinnati-bengals-tickets.html?wsUser=717', 'text': 'Tickets', 'isExternal': True, 'isPremium': False}]
...

[25 rows x 16 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

`json.items()` returns not just the values but the keys also, meaning that the first value in `teams` is the string "sports" and the second value is what you are looking for, the list. That's what is causing the error.

Edit: You want to do `for key, teams in teams_json.items()` not `for teams in teams_json.items()`